# How to redefine spybean per test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test, spy

I've got a SpringBootTest with a spyBean:

```
@SpyBean
private MyProperties myProperties;
```

I'd like to test the behaviour of the component under test with different values within myProperties. I have noticed, however, that when I change the values of myProperties in a single test, the next tests get the value set in the previous test and when I try to reset the value:

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
   myProperties = new MyProperties();
}
```

The subsequent change in individual test has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@MockBean` or `@SpyBean` mocks/spies on instance created by spring context and spring context is cached when running multiple integration tests. One way to fix this is to add `@DirtiesContext` on next test but this is not recommended as it will slow down your tests. Other solution could be to inject `myProperties` using `ReflectionTestUtils` in next test like this

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    myProperties = new MyProperties();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classInstance,"myProperties", myProperties);
}
```

Comment: will be difficult though, because it is mockmvc what is autowired...

Comment: You can `@Autowire` controller in test class and inject using ReflectionTestUtils. That should work